# Cannot convert the series to <class 'int'`>

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data with an *Age* column. I want to remove all the rows that are aged more than 90 and less than 1856.

This is the head of the dataframe:

[image]

This is what I attempted:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, because the code is provided as a screenshot. It should be transcribed to text (and then it can be reopened).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your error is on line 2.  `df['intage'] = int(df['age'])` is not valid, and you can't pass a pandas series to the int function.

You need to use `astype` if df['age'] is object dtype.

```
df['intage'] = df['age'].astype(int)
```

Or since you are subtracting two dates, you need to use the dt accessor with the days attribute to get the number of days as an integer:

```
df['intage'] = df['age'].dt.days
```

Comment: I cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]

Comment: @FanZhao Nope. use the .dt.days method below.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `dtype` is `timedelta64[ns]` you can either use between, specifying two `timedeltas` as the endpoints, or you can first convert the days to a numeric type using `numpy`.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [83, 108, 83, 63, 81]})
df['age'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.age, unit='days')
```

Find those between 82 and 107 days:

```
df[df.age.between(pd.to_timedelta(82, unit='days'), pd.to_timedelta(107, unit='days'))]
#      age
#0 83 days
#2 83 days
```

With `numpy`

```
df[(df.age/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).between(82, 107)]
#      age
#0 83 days
#2 83 days
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to extract days from the `timedelta` variables you have within the `age` column.

In the below toy example, you can see how you can achieve that:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta as td

# Create example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([td(83),td(108),td(83),td(63),td(81)], columns=["age"])
print df

# Get days from timedeltas
df.age = df.age.apply(lambda x: x.days)
print df

# Filter ages
df = df[df.age.between(91,1956, inclusive=True)]
print df
```

It results in the below output:

```
>>>
       age
0  83 days
1 108 days
2  83 days
3  63 days
4  81 days
   age
0   83
1  108
2   83
3   63
4   81
   age
1  108
```