# python TypeError datetime.datetime cannot convert the series to class int

Tags: python, datetime, typeerror

Hope you can help me. I want to check if a date is valid or not. I've read that I can do this with datetime. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="latin1")

dfTest = pd.DataFrame()
dfTest['year'] = df.GEBURTSTAG.dt.year
dfTest['month'] = df.GEBURTSTAG.dt.month
dfTest['day'] = df.GEBURTSTAG.dt.day

dfTest['check'] = dt.datetime(dfTest.year, dfTest.month, dfTest.day)
```

If I run that code the following TypeError shows up:

> cannot convert the series to class 'int'

I can't find the problem.

Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865367/cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-int

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot convert the series to <class 'int'\`>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865367/cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-int)

Comment: thx for your answer. I've already tried that but same TypError shows up. dtype in year, month and day is int64

Answer (score 0):

Use .astype(int)

```
dfTest['year'] = df.GEBURTSTAG.dt.year.astype(int)
dfTest['month'] = df.GEBURTSTAG.dt.month.astype(int)
dfTest['day'] = df.GEBURTSTAG.dt.day.astype(int)
```

To convert numpy.int64 to int:

```
dfTest = (pd.DataFrame()).to_dict()
```

`.tolist()` also works.

Comment: thx for your answer. I've already tried that but same TypError shows up. dtype in year, month and day is int64

Comment: @Chuck try now.

Comment: Now an AttributeError shows up: 'dict' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: @Chuck once you have converted it to dictionary, surf through it using valid key. dfTest is now a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, dict shows now the same TypeError: cannot convert the series to class int. That is so strange

Comment: Yes it is so strange

Comment: I think I know where the problem is but I haven't a solution yet. If I write this dfTest['check'] = dt.datetime(dfTest.year[0], dfTest.month[0], dfTest.day[0]) then without error but every row has the same value. What I need is that every row should pick that specific value without a loop function.