# Problem : Relationship between the length of a film that lasts between 60 and 200 minutes and its average rating

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to display, with a curve, the relationship between the length of a film that lasts between 60 and 200 minutes and its average rating on IMDb :

```
movies['duree'] = movies[(movies.duree<200) | (movies.duree>60)] #ERROR is HERE
sns.relplot(x=movies['duree'], y="averageRating", kind='line', data=movies)
```

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making the conversion correctly, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

movies = pd.DataFrame({
    'duration':["95 min","118 min","143 min","89 min","91 min","221 min"],
    "averageRating":[6.8,5.3,6.4,7.8,4.6,7.7],
    "listed_in":['A','B','C','D','E','F']
})
```

If I run your code I get the same error. Hard to trouble shoot unless you provide the full data frame, or try to locate where the string conversion failed. If I do this on the example, it works, and note, you subset the dataframe and pass it to plot:

```
movies['duree'] = movies['duration'].str.slice(0,-4).astype('int')
sns.relplot(x='duree', y="averageRating", kind='line', 
data=movies[(movies.duree<200) | (movies.duree>60)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like `movies.duree` is a string and not an integer. Try this:

```
movies['duree'] = movies[(int(movies.duree)<200) | (int(movies.duree)>60)]
```

Comment: I have got this erroe now: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865757/10875870

Comment: ```movies['duree'] = movies['duree'].astype(int)

movies['duree'] = movies[(int(movies.duree)<200) | (int(movies.duree)>60)]
sns.relplot(x=movies['duree'], y="averageRating", kind='line', data=movies)``` I'v got the same error... maybe it's come from my past code ? ```movies = df[df['type'] == 'Movie']

movies = df[df['type'] == 'Movie'].copy()

movies['duration'] = movies['duration'].astype(object).str[:-4]

movies.rename(columns = {'duration':'duree'}, inplace=True)

movies.astype({'duree': 'int64'}).dtypes

movies```